# Responsive CSS with high-res smart phones and tablets

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I am having a issue when I try to make a web app responsive to screen-size.

I have css that I want to use for smartphones (iPhone, Andriod, blackberry, windows phone), and also have CSS I want to use for tablets.

My test devices are an iPad 3 (768 x 1024) and blackberry 10 (768 x 1280). and the widths being the same is an issue because my css starts with:

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px){
    //enter code here`code here
}
```

Because the blackberry has slightly better resolution, it renders the CSS I don't want to  use for it. Is there another way I'm suppose to check the media type? I was wondering if there is a way to check the width with a measurable distance (cm or in). not sure how to solve this.

thanks in advance

Comment: The Blackberry 10 is a phone?  Usually high-resolution phones don't report their actual resolution to the browser.  Neither do high resolution tablets, for that matter.  In fact, the iPad 3 isn't 768x1024, it's 1536x2048.

Comment: Actually, you can grab the display sizes, pixel densities, orientation and other elements quite easily using javascript/CSS media queries, you just need to know how to use them.

Comment: @media screen and (min-resolution: 300dpi) { … }

Comment: Chris, in my javascript i checked the width and height and those were the number that came back for the 2 devices, im assuming thats the same thing the css considers when loading the styles

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The “pixels” that are used in CSS declarations and when the browser reports the screen size of the client device have nothing to do with the actual real-world pixels on a device's screen. The “pixels” that are used in CSS are essentially an abstract construct created specifically for us web developers. To concern your self with the actual amount of real-world pixels on a high-resolution mobile screen is, for most web applications, completely unnecessary and will only lead you to utter madness.

You can determine the browser and device type by inspecting the `navigator.userAgent` property in JavaScript. For example, to test for (practically) any mobile device:

```
 // if mobile === true, 99% chance the device is mobile.
var mobile = (/iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));
```

You can of course inspect `navigator.userAgent` to determine if the user is on a specific type of device or browser that you are particularly concerned about or having a problem with.

But again, in my personal experience, clever, simple, and **flexible** responsive CSS design (supported by media queries and JavaScript, too, of course) will render beautifully on 99% of device/browser combinations without having to resort to inspecting `navigator.userAgent` to create different styles for individual devices.

Comment: +1 for a descriptive response. You can use `-o-min-device-pixel-ratio` amongst others (in media queries) to determine the device more closely etc.

Comment: I'll take a look at that right now while we're on the subject. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I guess that's opera-specific? I have read all the media queries on MDN. Haven't gotten the time to look at documentation for other browsers :-)

Comment: Sorry, yes, they vary for diff browsers, but worth exploring.

Comment: Oh, definitely. "All you know and all you see is all your life will ever be." eerrr . . . I guess in my case it's all my code will ever be 8P

Comment: orb, i was trying your solution and for some reason when i opened up my site with a smartphone mobile was false :( i was using a blackberry 10 device.

Comment: oh never mind, i added "bb10" to the list of devices and it worked. thank you orb now i can know which css i can load :)

Comment: Ah, well in that case I will have to update that regex. Thank's for the heads up. I wonder a if there is a way the community could work together to keep that regex updated . . .

Answer (score 2):

You can also restrict your styles to the height:

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px) and (max-height:1024px){
    // iPAD
}
```

Comment: thats true, but how would i stop a smartphone with the same width and height in px from using this css too?

Comment: So you want to have different styles on tablets and phones? That's not possible afaik. There are a few more statements for `@media` which maybe will bring you near, but you never can be 100% sure.

Comment: @LinusCaldwell You can, but it's awkward to maintain and parse the userAgent vars as they don't adhere to strict specifications. `@media` queries will get you fairly close.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the meta tag viewport in your html header :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

To sum up :

> width = device width x pixel density

(Galaxy S4 : 1080 = 360 x 3)

This metatag allow you to catch the device width instead of the "faked width" (360 instead of 1080)

Some good reading :

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag
- http://screensiz.es/phone
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/mobifying/#toc-meta